# In Ember can the render helper get its model from the route instead of from its parameter?

Tags: ember.js

On a template you can use the {{render 'route' model}} helper to embed a template and controller into another template, but this will set the model passed as an argument as the model. Is there a way to embed a route into a template but have the model come from the ebeded route's model hook? The reason why I can't use the parameter method is that the route's model is an RSVP hash and it depends on a dynamic segment.

Comment: Did you try to pass an id instead of model or call this helper without parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a template backed by the route, you shouldn't try to embed it somehow, just define new nested route in your router, create a tempalte and put `{{outlet}}` instead of `{{render}}`. It will do absolutely the same - resolve the route, fetch the model, setup controller and render given template.

If you still need to embed async data via `{{render}}` helper in some reason, you can use conditionals:

```
{{#if model.length}}
    {{render 'template' model}}
{{/if}}
```